# Measure RMS voltage from AC Grid

Tags: microcontroller, ac, rms

**Circuit design**

I need design a circuit for read rms AC grid, its function is obtain the RMS value  and generate a PWM signal, this PWM signal feeds my AC/DC LED driver (PWM/1-10V input pin), the voltage grid comes from TRIAC dimmer so I think in this approach would be fine:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa552/slaa552.pdf

In the page 3, as you can see, it uses an cap-drop supply and resistor divider to reduce the voltage level. The AMC1100 adds isolated capability. ACMAINSENSE gives me direct access to AC level with 1.32 volts of offset and the LM339 it's a zero cross detection.

[image: Sine wave + offset]

**PIC controller**

Finally I have, and sine wave + offset and I need to calculate the RMS. I don't need neither high precision or high exactly. My doubts How I get RMS value? 
I have thought, I will use a lowpass filter, to get the mean value, and subtract it (by software) to the no-filter signal, and calculate the RMS by this method:

[rms calc graph method](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/rms-voltage.html)

and finally calculate rms by sqrt(DCmean^2 + rms^2).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Why I need measure RMS from grid? In my job, we working with AC/DC drivers for street lighting, now some customers they have a dimming control for reduce the output power from the luminaire (lamps High Pressure sodium steam), and we offered a LED conversion, PSU + LED retrofit. They wants use the same dimming method, so our LED driver it have a 1-10V input to apply dimming, so I need a module to read RMS value and generate 1- 10 output.

Comment: You have some fundamental problems/miconseptions with your question that make it impossible to understand and answer.

Comment: (1) Is your question how to convert true RMS voltage reading to 1 to 10 V DC signal? If so, (2) What input AC voltage gives 1 V DC? (2) What input AC voltage gives 10 V DC? (3) Is the AC symmetrical. (Can we just measure positive half-cycles?) (4) Are you using a micro-controller? (5) What precision do you require? (6) Can we just measure the phase angle and calculate the RMS rather than measure the voltage? If so, (7) what is minimum phase angle (0°?) and maximum (180°?)?

Comment: @Transistor no, I want read RMS only, after that I make my own conversion... Yes, it's AC grid. I use a microcontroller. The problem is what I don't know the signal, just that the RMS value it's variable, it's for street lighting.

Comment: @Andyaka why? I think it's clear, get the RMS value from AC grid with low sample rate, and enought precission+accuracy for dimming pourposses.

Comment: Yes, but *why* are you need to know the RMS to control the LEDs? If the LEDs are driven from an LED PSU then what relevance is the mains RMS? And why is the mains phase-angle controlled. The reason Andy and I are asking is that we often see questions asked where the OP has decided on the wrong approach to a problem and is now mired in the details of how to get that to work. Please add some context into your question.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry I will add more info in the first post.

Comment: @A.martinez Write a clear specific question instead of any suggestions...

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are trying to dim an LED power supply with a triac dimmer.

If this is correct then there is no need to measure the RMS value of the dimmer voltage. Instead you can measure the phase angle and dim in proportion to that. The incandescent lamps won't light linearly with knob position but it's generally not a problem.

[image]

*Figure 1. Triac phase-angle control.*

If you want to linearise it  somewhat better you can use a lookup table rather than calculate.

[image]

*Figure 2. Graph of mean-squared and root-mean-squared output as a function of phase-angle.*

[image]

*Figure 3. The lookup calculations for the graphs.*

Answer (score 1):

> My doubts How I get RMS value?

I'm assuming you're using some kind of micro-controller.
You calculate RMS (root mean square) on one period of absolute samples. But root takes long, so you do the square and mean first, on each sample. And the root at a slower rate.

First you need to create a mean value with the squares. Each sample gets squared, and put into a moving average filter.

```
x = abs(x);
x = x * x;
fifo_in(x);
accumulator += x;
```

RMS must be phase locked, else it is inaccurate. The fifo must be a multiple of periods worth of samples long. Or just one period.

```
while(fifo_count() > samples_in_period) 
    accumulator -= fifo_out();
```

The means you also need to measure, or guess, the frequency.

Then when you need the RMS value, you calculate the mean, and the root.
The mean takes a division, the root takes a lot of divisions. Division are slow, that why you can't run RMS on each sample. Unless processing time is plentiful.

```
mean = accumulator / fifo_count();
rms = sqrt(mean);
```

That's it really. The tricky bits are the number sizes. Accumulator quickly gains size based on the number of samples it takes in the buffer. And the processing time of the divisions limits your effective measurement rate.

Running the above at should be easy for a 48 MHz Cortex M3, if a fixed point math implementation is used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. My RMS sample rate is lower, I think 1 rms value per second would be fine...What do you mean with "rms must be phase locked"? The zero cross detection is mandatory?I will plan use a 8 bit ucontroller like pic16 or similar.

Comment: hi, I was messing with 2 ideas...one the solution above... and the other solution use a specific IC to energy measurement like the microchip MCP39F511. what do you think?

Comment: @A.martinez If you do not care about the energy, that is not necessary. In fact, the update rate of such chip might be too slow for you.